# Why are mobile OS'es still tied to vendors?

Tags: operating-system, cross-platform, mobile-phones, platform, embedded

Modern mobile phones have come far since their beginnings over 30 years ago. Especially smartphones, which are essentially miniature PC's, capable of all the same things, if at a bit slower pace. So if cellphones have followed in the footsteps of PCs, why hasn't their software? Why can't I take my mobile phone and install the latest edition of Android on it, like I install the latest edition of Windows or Ubuntu on my PC? Is this solely a marketing decision (market segregation, forcing to buy a new phone if you want a different OS, etc.), or is there some fundamental problem preventing the good old OS+driver model?

Comment: This is not a programming question, it's a marketing question.  Take it somewhere appropriate.

Comment: @Paul Tomblin - such as? I believe this is still relevant for StackOverflow.

Comment: It's not a programming question.  Therefore it is not relevant or on-topic for StackOverflow.  As to where it *does* belong, that's your problem, not mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because there was no need for it. A cellphone is like a toaster. Nearly nobody want’s to change the firmware of a toaster (except for Cylons). Most people simply want to use it.

Interchangeable firmwares mean additional work for the vendor which can’t be justified if nobody will use this feature.

Comment: It would be easier for the vendor him/her/it/*self... Less maintenance IMO..

Comment: @rubenvb: Not neccessarily. I don't want to install skype or quake on my phone. And there also security reasons: if my phone have unique OS it would be safer from exploits. And usually it's full of personal data.

Comment: @ruslik: then Dell should use a per system Windows? You can't fix a buggy OS by using different versions with the same bug I'd think... Why can "hackers" get it done so "easily"? Of course, less strict quality control, but it does work very well, there's no denying that... Heck, most phones use the same hardware (especially CPU).

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, by [rooting your phone](http://www.androidpolice.com/2010/04/15/rooting-explained-top-5-benefits-of-rooting-your-android-phone/). In fact, it is possible to put Android onto iPhone (and theoretically possible to do the opposite). It's not more widespread because the phone and software are tied together very tightly, that's why you never have to worry about drivers. For you to change the operating system and perform other tasks that require similar levels of access and modification, it requires manufacturers to update all those specific details, hence it is rare. In the past there have been phones (such as the Omnia) where the manufacturer provides these updates for owners.